# Get callback value outside in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have following script

```
var count =   exec('wc -l <  '+filePath, function (error, results) {
        console.log(results);
        return results;
    });
```

Now I want to print results value outside of callback like if I print count that results value should be print.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `execSync` from the same module(`child_process`)

```
const { execSync } = require("child_process");
const filePath = process.argv.slice(2)[0]
var count = execSync("wc -l <  " + filePath).toString().trim();
console.log(count);
```

> Same thing using async-await:

```
const { promisify } = require("util");
const { exec: execCB } = require("child_process");
const exec = promisify(execCB);
const filePath = process.argv.slice(2)[0];
async function main() {
  var count = await exec("wc -l <  " + filePath).then(res => res.stdout.toString().trim());
  console.log(count);
}
main();
```